# Select Data from DB in android Studio

Tags: java, sql, android-studio, select

I have error in Call Function Get Data. I have error in this line.

```
  } catch (Exception e) {
        if (!mInstrumentation.onException(activity, e)) {
            throw new RuntimeException(
                "Unable to start activity " + component
                + ": " + e.toString(), e);
        }
    }
```

**package com.example.cyberartillery;

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.io.IOException;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        DataBaseHelper myDbHelper = new DataBaseHelper(this);
        myDbHelper = new DataBaseHelper(this);

        try {
            myDbHelper.createDataBase();
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            throw new Error("Unable to create database");
        }

        try {
            myDbHelper.openDataBase();
        }catch(SQLException sqle){
            throw sqle;
        }

        Cursor a = myDbHelper.getData();


        findViewById(R.id.MainImage1).setClickable(true);
        findViewById(R.id.MainImage1).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (v.equals(findViewById(R.id.MainImage1))) {


                }
            }
        });

    }

    //@Override
    //public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        //getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
     //   return true;
   // }

}**
```

This is DataBaseHelper Class

```
package com.example.cyberartillery;

import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;

public class DataBaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    // путь к базе данных вашего приложения
    private static String DB_PATH = "/data/data/com.example.cyberartillery/databases/";
    private static String DB_NAME = "northwind";
    private SQLiteDatabase myDataBase;
    private final Context mContext;

    /**
     * Конструктор
     * Принимает и сохраняет ссылку на переданный контекст для доступа к ресурсам приложения
     * @param context
     */
    public DataBaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DB_NAME, null, 1);
        this.mContext = context;
    }

    /**
     * Создает пустую базу данных и перезаписывает ее нашей собственной базой
     * */
    public void createDataBase() throws IOException {
        boolean dbExist = checkDataBase();

        if(dbExist){
            //ничего не делать - база уже есть
        }else{
            //вызывая этот метод создаем пустую базу, позже она будет перезаписана
            this.getReadableDatabase();

            try {
                copyDataBase();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                throw new Error("Error copying database");
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Проверяет, существует ли уже эта база, чтобы не копировать каждый раз при запуске приложения
     * @return true если существует, false если не существует
     */
    private boolean checkDataBase(){
        SQLiteDatabase checkDB = null;

        try{
            String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
            checkDB = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);
        }catch(SQLiteException e){
            //база еще не существует
        }
        if(checkDB != null){
            checkDB.close();
        }
        return checkDB != null ? true : false;
    }

    /**
     * Копирует базу из папки assets заместо созданной локальной БД
     * Выполняется путем копирования потока байтов.
     * */
    private void copyDataBase() throws IOException{
        //Открываем локальную БД как входящий поток
        InputStream myInput = mContext.getAssets().open(DB_NAME);

        //Путь ко вновь созданной БД
        String outFileName = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;

        //Открываем пустую базу данных как исходящий поток
        OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);

        //перемещаем байты из входящего файла в исходящий
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int length;
        while ((length = myInput.read(buffer))>0){
            myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
        }

        //закрываем потоки
        myOutput.flush();
        myOutput.close();
        myInput.close();
    }

    public void openDataBase() throws SQLException {
        //открываем БД
        String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
        myDataBase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);
    }

    @Override
    public synchronized void close() {
        if(myDataBase != null)
   

     myDataBase.close();
    super.close();
}

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    }

    public Cursor getData() {
        return myDataBase.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM Categories WHERE CategoryID = 2", null);
    }
    // Здесь можно добавить вспомогательные методы для доступа и получения данных из БД
    // вы можете возвращать курсоры через "return myDataBase.query(....)", это облегчит их использование
    // в создании адаптеров для ваших view
}
```

Please Help me fix this issue. I want to Select Data from exists Database.

Comment: what is the error?

Comment: } catch (Exception e) {
        if (!mInstrumentation.onException(activity, e)) {
            throw new RuntimeException(
                "Unable to start activity " + component
                + ": " + e.toString(), e);
        }
    }

This is a error

Comment: that is not an error. That is your code. What is the output in logcat when the error is thrown?